# Fancybox works on one page, but not on another

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have one page where fancybox works,
http://interscript.pl/domy/?p=628

and another where it doesn't. Where is mistake?
http://interscript.pl/domy/?cat=4

EDIT:

```
<a href="http://interscript.pl/domy/wp-content/uploads/Tulips.jpg" data-title="asdfasdfas dfsad 12341234 23" data-link="" class="fancybox" rel="grupa">
    <div class="wpis">
        <div class="obszar">
            <img src="http://interscript.pl/domy/wp-content/uploads/Tulips-160x125.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="hover"></div>
    </div>
</a>
```

JS: `$('a.fancybox').fancybox();`

Comment: Would you mind including the JavaScript and HTML section of the part that is not working ??

Comment: @Pawal Sorry, I've edited first post.

Answer (score 0):

You've applied fancybox to all "a tags " -> $('a.fancybox').fancybox();

But your "image" is not "a"  -> *http://interscript.pl/domy/?cat=4*

```
<div class="obszar">
<img src="http://interscript.pl/domy/wp-content/uploads/Tulips-160x125.jpg">
</div>
```

insert this code  in your jquery codes

```
$(".obszar img").fancybox();
```

or edit your code such this;

```
<div class="obszar">
<a href="#"><img src="http://interscript.pl/domy/wp-content/uploads/Tulips-160x125.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, this is how fancybox plugin works:

1. You put <a> tag with href attribute inside - this is link to your hi-res image

2. Inside you can put everything, but usually people put there <img> tag with thumbnail of image.

3. As documentation says, you have to run plugin on <a> tags.

Comment: @michail_w : well, if you understand how the plugin works, then you missed to include the `<a>` tag in your html code

Comment: @JFK no, I didn't miss `<a>`. Look at code example in first post, there is always `<a>` tag as parent of each fancybox photo.